# MonkeyPatch a module's const

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a 3rd party library which has this code:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true })
exports.SOMEVAR = 'foo'
class FooBar {
    something() {
        console.log(exports.TRACE_CONTEXT_HEADER_NAME)
    }
}
```

And I want to change it so that the `SOMEVAR` is something else.

I have attempted to do this:

```
from * as foobar from 'foobar'
foobar.SOMEVAR = 'baz'
```

but that doesn't seem to work. It changes it for local references, but not inside the module. Is there anyway to monkeypatch this value, so that the module actually prints `baz` instead of `foo`?

---

In case it's relevant, I am using typescript, and the `foobar.d.ts` file looks like this:

```
export declare const SOMEVAR = "foo";
export declare class FooBar {
    something(): null;
}
```

Comment: just curious as to _why_ you would want to do this?

Comment: basically, this library is assuming a certain "key' in my http headers, but the key is actually something else in my org. I dont want to have to rewrite the entire library just because the key in the header is a different name.

Answer (score 0):

The example you have presented should work fine.

## Complete code

// foobar.ts:

```
export const SOMEVAR = "foo";
class FooBar {
  something() {
    console.log(SOMEVAR);
  }
}
setTimeout(() => {
  new FooBar().something();
}, 1000);
```

// index.ts:

```
import * as foobar from "./foobar";
(foobar as any).SOMEVAR = "baz";
```

Notice the console logs out `baz`.

[image]

Comment: So, if I run it using ts-node, then that is correct, this works. But when I build the module separately as a esmodule, then it doesn't work. I guess typescript compilation is doing something weird that flattens/copies the imports.

Comment: You have to use `module:commonjs` in your tsconfig. This will cause `exports` to be created which you are mutating 